# Execute a single Node.js file in Windows command from anywhere

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, path

I have a Node.js file in `c:\scripts` and want to execute them in Windows command from anywhere by `node my-file.js`. It's kind of requirement for execute a bat file, which I can put the folder in `%PATH%`. I've tried to include `c:\scripts` in `%NODE_PATH%` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

nodejs has the notion of executables ... for example package

```
jslint
```

once installed can be directly executed from anywhere ... its installed using the -g flag as in :

```
npm install -g jslint
```

just like normal packages its code is installed in dir defined by env var

```
NODE_PATH
```

additionally its executable lives in the bin dir which is by default added to PATH during initial nodejs install

on linux

```
type jshint
jshint is /home/stens/node-v5.8.0/bin/jshint


echo $NODE_PATH
/home/stens/node-v5.8.0/lib/node_modules
```

on windows box similar happens just examine your PATH to see the nodejs bin dir ... on linux its a location relative to $NODE_PATH

UPDATE :

Alternative to above you can put a some-file (do Windows equivalent to chmod +x some-file to make it an executable)  into a dir listed in your $PATH ... for example on linux if I issue

```
type jslint
```

which is found because PATH contains dir /home/stens/node-v5.8.0/bin   ... above command outputs :

```
jslint is hashed (/home/stens/node-v5.8.0/bin/jslint)
```

then show contents

cat /home/stens/node-v5.8.0/bin/jslint

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var main = require("../lib/main.js");

main.runMain(main.parseArgs());
```

you can see the executable file in just nodejs code with the 1st line

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

which tell the system to execute it using node (dunno the Windows way but similar must be available)

so its executed using

```
jslint blah input-blah parm-blah goes-blah here-blah
```

Hopefully this tips you in the right direction

Comment: Can I just execute a single file without making it a module under `%NODE_PATH%`?

Comment: Yes see the UPDATE :

Comment: Thanks, but Windows command doesn't support mark like `#!/usr/bin/env node` I think.